# Show that R is an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let R be the relation on Z × Z, that is elements of this relation are
pairs of pairs of integers, such that ((a, b),(c, d)) ∈ R if and only if
a + d = b + c. Show that R is an equivalence relation.

So I know I need to show that it's reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. I have an answer but I think my wording doesn't really look proper and I think the transitive part is incorrect.

Reflexive: if a+d = b+c, then a+d = a+d, which is true.

Symmetric: if a+d = b+c then, b+c = a+d, which is true.

Transitive: if a+d = b+c and  b+c = e+f, then a+d=e+f, this is true because since a+d = b+c, and b+c = e+f, then a+d must be equal to e+f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it appears you messed up on the transitive part:  if $((a,b), (c,d))\in R $ and $((c,d), (e,f))\in R $, we need to show  $((a,b), (e,f))\in R $.  Now  $a+d=b+c $ and $c+f=d+e $.  So $a+f=b+c-d+d+e-c=b+e $.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are my other answers ok? Should I change the wording ?

Comment: @RajanGrewal. Come to think of it it looks like the other two parts are off a little too...  it's a good idea to write out precisely what you are trying to prove...  There's lots of letters flying around. ..

Comment: @RajanGrewal You need to show  $((a,b), (a,b))\in R $ for all $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z×\mathbb Z $for the reflexive property;   and that $((a,b), (c,d))\in R \implies  ((c,d), (a,b))\in R $ for all $(a,b), (c,d)\in \mathbb Z ×\mathbb Z  $, for the symmetric property. ..